# How can I sort users by how many of my questions they close voted?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, users, statistics

I posted questions. Some got closed. I'd like to see which users close voted them most often.

E.g., display: user X close voted to close 23 of my questions, user Y close voted to close 17 of my questions, etc.

I believe we can only see users who submitted close votes for closed questions, so I'm ok to sort users by how many *closed* questions I posted they close voted.

---

FYI: [What's the goal of listing the users that voted to close a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174183/178179)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1502/discussion-on-question-by-franck-dernoncourt-how-can-i-sort-users-by-how-many-of).

Comment: Wow, the amount of  users who think there **could be** no abuse of close voting privileges by a single user/group of users and therefore all such voters are above any kind of, forget scrutiny but - bare minimum transparency is amazing -_- It's almost as if they want to worship these close voters

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'll leave the ethical discussion about how this analysis can be (ab)used to others and focus just on how you can obtain this data.

SEDE has a table PostHistory that stores in a row with PostHistoryTypeId = 10 the successful closure of a Post. (Close votes or flags that didn't lead to an actual closure are not available in SEDE). In the Text column a JSON is stored that has a Voters property with an array of objects where for each voter Id, DisplayName and whether they used their binding gold badge hammer.

T-SQL has the OPENJSON function that can be used to transform JSON arrays into proper tables so they can be queried and/or projected as for any other column. Here I use a CROSS join after your questions are selected.

Combining all this leads to [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1266618?UserId=395857):

```sql
select v.Id [User Link]
     , count(*) [# Closed]
from posthistory ph
inner join posts p on p.id = ph.postid
cross apply openjson(text, '$.Voters') with (Id integer  '$.Id') v
where ph.posthistorytypeid = 10 -- closed
and p.owneruserid = ##userid:int?395857##
group by v.id
order by count(*) desc
```

When run today on your Stack Overflow account, no users have been involved in close voting  a question of yours more then once

[image: Result of the query as run on 2020-07-24, showing links to users and their count, all counts are 1]

It is rather uninteresting.

As this information should remain private according to some users let's also have a look at the [Network Wide Close voters of Franck](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1266785?accountid=169656).

Who could have guessed, he is close vote stalking himself, further some moderators and a gold badge holder on MSE.

[image: shows Frank as top result, second is David Postil, third is Rob]

That is more interesting.

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the unforgettable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1501/discussion-between-rubiksmoose-and-colleenv).

Comment: What is `$.Voters` or `text`?

Comment: @TheMaster `Text` is the column from the `PostHistory` table. The `$.Voters` is a JSON Path expression to get the value of the Voters property from the JSON document that is stored in the `Text` column. See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thanks. I did skim the link before..But why isn't it `ph.text` and just `text`?

Comment: @TheMaster there is only one `text` column in all joined tables so it is not needed here to qualify the table. I can't do that for the `id` column for example because that column exists in both `posts` and `posthistory`. Some might call not using `ph` a style issue, some might call it sloppy / lazy. I'm not religious about it and use both forms, adding table qualifiers when required.