# Is there a way to find out if I've ever both voted to close a question and posted an answer to it?

Tags: support, answers, vote-to-close, gaming-the-system, gamification

I just noticed that someone voted to close a question and posted an excellent answer at the same time. I wanted to tell them that I thought it was unfair to do both with an argument involving gamesmanship, but then remembered that calling out others on their close voting is discouraged because that information is no longer generally viewable to all users.

So instead I'd like to find out if *I've ever done this* because maybe I have and if so I'd like to *judge myself!*

**Question:** is there a way to find out if I've ever both voted to close a question and posted an answer to it?

I'm only asking about checking my own behavior, presumably there is no way that one user could do this for another user.

---

What I'd originally commented *then thought better and deleted:*

> `-1` because writing an excellent answer and yet also voting to close seems unfair to me because it allows you to post an answer but moves to block others from positing other answers to which it can be compared. Doing both seems to say (to me at least) "this can be the only answer; there is nothing that can possibly be added nor additional perspectives to consider".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Closing Etiquette: Why Do Some Answer \*and\* Close?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4283/closing-etiquette-why-do-some-answer-and-close)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ **not it does not**, that's a completely different question and I see no answers there that answer my question "Is there a way to find out if..."

Comment: Can we first get consensus, that there need to be actions done in that situation, before asking for a way to detect it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I agree with the OP that their request is not a duplicate of the question suggested by you. The only suggestion I can offer the OP is to use the search tool; type their user number and include the command `closed:yes`. This will pull up any answers of theirs on questions that have been subsequently closed.

Comment: @Mari-LouA thanks, I will give that a try. I'm not very adept at using the search tool beyond keywords but I know there is a tutorial.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ in this case it turns out that the answer to my question is most revealing ;-) Thank goodness it was posted before posting an answer was blocked by insta-closers!

Comment: For the record: The most disputed behavior in this category, is giving an answer, and immediately dupehammer the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is one of the things [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) can do. You can run [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1270588/questions-closed-and-answered-by-the-same-user) to find out. [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/space/query/1270588/questions-closed-and-answered-by-the-same-user?UserId=295232#resultSets) are the results for your top site:

[image]

SEDE is refreshed once a week, on Sunday morning. I wrote this one based on [another query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/351239/295232) by resident SEDE guru @rene.

As you probably notice when going through the list, there are various reasons to both close and answer the same question. I'll have a look at situations where I did so later ...

Comment: Ha! It seems that I should then judge myself quite harshly, *thanks!* I'll check the SEDE script out once I get back to my laptop, I'm trying to understand why the same question appears twice in your list. **update** Oh I posted two answers to that, I remember that one now. ;-)

Comment: Be aware that this only shows questions that are actually closed, in other words: where the close vote had indeed the desired outcome. A close vote that aged away is not captured in SEDE.

Comment: True, and it doesn't include deleted questions either.

Comment: I dont quite get the “results for your top site” part of your answer (+1, BTW). Where is a reference to a specific site within that SEDE query?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks! That refers to the top site for uhoh, who posted the question. The site isn't in the SEDE code, it's in the *URL*. [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1270588/questions-closed-and-answered-by-the-same-user) is your list. Just under the parameters, there's a box where you can change the site the query should run for.

Answer (score 3):

Since @Glorfindel has already provided an SEDE query to do what you have asked about, I want to add an answer that challenges whether this is (always) a poor behavior.

I sometimes vote to close a question and more or less simultaneously provide an answer to it. At other times I may vote to close a question years after writing an answer to it. I do neither for reasons of gamesmanship.

The reason I answer is to help the person that has asked a question and for me to do this their question must be in the topic scope of the site.

The reason I vote to close is because they have asked a question that needs to be improved.

I see the two as being not mutually exclusive.  Focused Q&A is hard for many and takes years for some to adjust to, so rather than always seeing their poorly asked questions closed without an answer, I think it is OK for them to occasionally feel they got a lucky break in the form of an answer to a question that did not really deserve it.

To get more answers to those questions they still need to get better at asking clear and focused on-topic questions.

Comment: I believe I have once or twice voted to close a question and also answered it—but the close vote was to migrate it to a different site. I felt that the detailed answer would still be useful at the other site, and I didn't want to simply close vote and forget about it, or leave an inadequate comment. But that hasn't happened very often.